# Error in integrating Admob in Android

Tags: android, admob

I have a completed app and I tried adding admob.

I got the publisher id and I have added it in manifest file. When I run in the device, the app works fine in all other activities. However, when I move to the activity where the admob ad has been placed, my app crashes, and in logcat it shows the following error:

The major errors shown in the logcat are as follows:

> 04-06 20:22:30.627: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2339):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mnn.image0114/com.menteon.speedimage0114.ResultPage}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error
>   inflating class com.admob.ads.AdView
>
> 04-06 20:22:30.627: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2339): Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error
>   inflating class com.admob.ads.AdView
>
> 04-06 20:22:30.627: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2339): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.admob.ads.AdView in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44ccc270

How to fix this error? Please help me.

Comment: did you add that admob jar file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a recent AdMob jar, you need to be using `com.google.ads.AdView`.  This is certainly the case in Sdk 4.04.

Having said that, I didn't put my AdViews directly into the XML, but used the following code to place the ads inside a LinearLayout within my XML -

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_ID);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adMob);
layout.addView(adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.setTesting(GlobalData.DebugBuild);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: what is this GlobalData....i tried using your answer but got red lines in those words

Comment: It's a flag I use to determine whether I'm making a release build or a debug build.  Basically use `adRequest.setTesting(true)` for a debug build or `adRequest.setTesting(true)` for a release build

Comment: can you pls answer my question in the following link     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576516/admob-cannot-be-viewed-in-android

Comment: I meant `adRequest.setTesting(false)` for a release build.  And it looks like you answered your own question from the above link?

Comment: sorry i have found answer for one issue only ...pls answer in this link                                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577958/admob-error-due-to-attrs-xml-in-android.... pls help me

Comment: Is that the only solution? why doesn't it work any more to add it in the xml?

Comment: ok, found the fix here: http://android.okhelp.cz/noclassdeffounderror-com-google-ads-adview-adt-17/

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it following the instructions here:
[NoClassDefFoundError when GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857539/noclassdeffounderror-when-googleanalyticstracker-getinstance)
It seems the new version 17 of ADT requires the libraries to be imported from a "libs" folder inside your project. So I just created the "libs" folder, imported my libs there, and then set them in the project's build path (basically following the instructions at the above link). It fixed both problems I had with admob and analytics code.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this I created a folder called /libs and copied the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.1.jar into it.  Worked like a Charm.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I agree with Steve the Sultan. I've tried the method with some additional modification to the AdView widget in the layout file. And I got this, http://blog.kerul.net/2012/08/example-how-to-install-google-admob-6x.html ...

I have this experience of having the apps crashing and displaying messages such as this - "Error inflating class com.admob.ads.AdView" . Doing some research and testing I concluded the following XML attribute to display the AdView;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg1"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="738a44d913034b9f"
        />  
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >







    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnkamus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/search" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Kesan" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btncadang"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cadang" />

</TableRow>


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```