# admob cannot be viewed in android

Tags: android, admob

i tried using Admob in my app by running it in a device and it showed nothing and i found the followig errors in logcat

`04-07 10:49:05.570: ERROR/Ads(1084): AdView missing required XML attribute adUnitId.
04-07 10:49:07.850: ERROR/Ads(1084): Could not find com.google.ads.AdActivity, please make sure it is registered in AndroidManifest.xml.`

But in manifest file i have mentioned the following lines
{`<meta-data android:value="axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"/> 
  <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdMobActivity"/>`}

What is my error...

I have totally  4 Activities in my App and i am trying to add the admob in my 4th activity.
whether i have to add the above said lines with that activity or anything else pls help me friends...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error shown can be fixed by adding the following to the manifest file:

`<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" />`

Comment: as per https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ it should be AdActivity, not AdMobActivity