# jsonfactory android error

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am trying to access Google Calendar in my Android 4.0 project. While I am trying to do that I am getting the following error message :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory

This is the message that is being displayed as soon as I run my application. I have imported all the necessary jar files and have also written the necessary import statements in my code.
I am not able to pin the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your ans is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857539/noclassdeffounderror-when-googleanalyticstracker-getinstance/9857669#9857669

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are adding the library right.
There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3643015/1376688) which explains very good
Hope this helps