# Android I get Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, exception

This is the error I get:

```
05-08 12:50:56.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1018): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
nl.h.energy.android.userinterface.FragmentEnergyUsage
```

I used breakpoints and I have determined that the error is on this line

```
1   bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
2     .setText("energy usage")
3     .setTabListener( 
4     new nl.h.energy.android.helper.TabListener
5      <nl.h.energy.android.userinterface.FragmentEnergyUsage>
6       (this,"energyUsage",  
7        nl.h.energy.android.userinterface.FragmentEnergyUsage.class)));
```

The error occurs on line 6/7 I hope I have provide enough info. 
These classe are classes that I have written my self so, no problems with me having to import these classes or that these classes are missing in Android

the TabListener looks like this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#newTab()

and the  FragementEnergyUsage class looks like this:

```
package nl.h.energy.android..userinterface;

import nl.h.energy.userinterface.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FragmentEnergyUsage extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Test", "hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.energy_usage, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void setText(String item) {
        TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
        view.setText(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've gotten NoClassDefFoundErrors in the past and it has usually been related to problems with Eclipse or a bad build or after upgrading my ADT plugins, etc.  First line of troubleshooting might be to restart Eclipse and do a Project > Clean.  Are these classes coming from a library project by any chance?

Comment: @Rich Um nope, thes classes aren't external but I will try your suggestion.

Comment: your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857539/noclassdeffounderror-when-googleanalyticstracker-getinstance/9857669#9857669

Comment: @Akki All my external jars are already in my lib folder, even before this error.

Comment: @mariomario not in lib folder. put jar files in libs folder

Comment: @mariomario the folder name should be libs not lib.

Answer (score 1):

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046298/android-update-17-seems-incompatible-with-external-jars/10046725#10046725)

also check whether you have registered all activity classes in your manifest file ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.example.SupportFragment
    at com.android.example.SupportFragmentActivity.onCreate()
```

on

```
SupportFragment extends SherlockFragment implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener
...
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

when trying to make a api 17 app compatible with api 8, the only indication was the logcat error above, so check that all your imported classes are supported if you get this error.