# How to solve NoClassDefFoundError preconditions?

Tags: android, nfc

I create NFC reader when I run it has stopped and logcat show java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.Precondition

How to solve it?
Please support me.

Comment: like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857539/noclassdeffounderror-when-googleanalyticstracker-getinstance/9857669#9857669

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using or modifying one of the SDK samples and need these libraries:

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/