# Regarding NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android

I have used the isEmpty and isBlank methods of apache's StringUtils Class. These methods worked in a fine manner, after couple of weeks suddenly i got the error

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils**

I was confused why this error happened suddenly.It would be fine if anyone help me to understand this suddenly happened.

People Saying that apache might have changed the definitionin their JAR file, is it a right one,i really confused why this suddenly happened , i removed the old jar from my build path and downloaded the same version of New Jar and added it to Build path, then this issue is resloved.

It is happening in the Market Code , there's no interaction with ADT and market code

so really confused on this issue?

Comment: here is your ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857539/noclassdeffounderror-when-googleanalyticstracker-getinstance/9857669#9857669

Comment: @Akki: i have added jar file in that manner only, it was recongized and worked fine , suddenly i got this exception and also i m not getting classnot found exception underrstand

Comment: you might be updated you ADT if yes make sure you have a folder name libs with all the jar file your project needed

Comment: @It is happening in the Market Code , there's no interaction with ADT and market code, please understand

Comment: when you uploaded your application recently?

Comment: @SankarGanesh sure that apache String Utils jar is missing. that's why this issue is coming.Add the jar and try to run again.

Answer (score 1):

This occurred to me too - after updating the Android SDK Tools. In current version (19), what you need to do is:

1. make libs/ folder in project's root directory, and put all jars there (folder's name is fixed "libs")
2. after this, go to project properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries, and remove all custom jars you previously added

Answer (score 0):

[NoClassDefFoundError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) says NoClassDefFoundError is Thrown if the JVM or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class and no definition of the class could be found.

Maybe [startup script is overriding Classpath environment variable](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html).

Comment: I understand , but my Question is , it  worked fine for the past 10 weeks, but i was wonder why JVM or Classloader facing this problem suddenly