# trying to call activity from a jar file in android - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-intent, jar

I had a Android APP with activity and everything. however, I am trying to turn it into library and use it in another app. the APP compiled as a JAR file just fine.

however, when I call an activity from jar file , it immediately fails with ClassNotFound exception.

this is how I am calling the intent:

```
    Intent dialerIntent = new Intent(this, SipHome.class);
    startActivity(dialerIntent);
```

here SipHome.class is defined in the library jar file.

The error that I get is:

```
05-23 17:23:36.081: E/AndroidRuntime(21634): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.thaifi.remote.db.DBProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thaifi.remote.db.DBProvider in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.thaifi.remote-2.apk]
```

any idea what might be the issue?

here is my manifest.xml for the jar file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.csipsimple"
    android:versionCode="1485"
    android:versionName="0.04-00" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: here is your ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857539/noclassdeffounderror-when-googleanalyticstracker-getinstance/9857669#9857669

Comment: actually i am adding the sourcecode of that library project to my current eclipse project, which works. this is not a compile time error, but runtime error.also i am on adt 1.8

Comment: nevertheless, i tried your suggestion..still no good :(

Comment: could you please show us the image of the attached lib project?

Comment: sure..but what do you mean imange? a screenshot? 
 http://www.flickr.com/photos/11145703@N06/7255006600/in/photostream

Comment: trying to call activity from a jar file in android????

Comment: yes!
"however, when I call an activity from jar file , it immediately fails with ClassNotFound exception."
is it even possible? that is what trying to figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simple as i found out.

simply declare the activity in manifest (even though the class for that activity is in another jar file) and call it like you would call any other activity.