# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Android after changing a class file

Tags: java, android

I have a jar library. I used Java Class File Editor (CE) to modify one class in this library. In this class, I changed a variable from `private static final` to `public static`. Afterwards, I put the newly modified class file into same jar library using WinRAR.

However, running the app on Android produces a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

How do I resolve the `NoClassDefFoundError`?

Please help.

Comment: Did you use zip compression to create your new `jar` file?

Comment: Where have you kept the jar file?

Comment: I put the jar file in a folder on the desktop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857539/noclassdeffounderror-when-googleanalyticstracker-getinstance/9857669#9857669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by RSA encryption.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that WinRAR has created a file that is no longer JAR compatible.  I'd recommend not using WinRAR.  Use the `jar` command to unpack that JAR file into a directory tree, make the change(s), and repack it again using `jar`.

Another possibility is that your change has triggered a code verification problem or similar.  Show us the complete error message and stacktrace for the exception?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(6245): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: I tried the jar command instead of WinRAR. But I still get NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Show us the complete stacktrace.  And use `jar -t` on the updated JAR file to make sure that the class is in the right place.

Comment: How to produce a stacktrace? Do you mean the messages on Logcat?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is related or if it's entirely possible that changing the contents of a class file could've affected this, but maybe you should just try doing Project -> Clean in Eclipse. Also, do try including the jar file in the /libs folder if you haven't already.

Furthermore, confirm that your Jar file is compressed properly when you recreated it.