# My Library jar file is not working in Eclipse But working fine in Net-Beans, Any Suggestion

Tags: java, android, sdk

My Library jar file is not working in Eclipse but working fine in Net-Beans, I tired but it shows

```
07-05 17:34:09.064: E/AndroidRuntime(560): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fi.joensuu.joyds1.calendar.IslamicCalendar
```

Any suggetions are Appreceated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857539/noclassdeffounderror-when-googleanalyticstracker-getinstance/9857669#9857669

Answer (score 0):

From Android Latest Version of `sdk` we must place external `jar files` in  a folder called `libs`.

1. create a new folder in the project named libs
2. place your external jar file in that folder
3. no need to give the path to the project in eclipse. It will automatically exists

Good luck

**EDIT**

You will need to add the library to your build path. You can do this by right clicking it in Package Explorer and selecting add to build path, or by editing the build settings manually.

Comment: I am folder lib folder in my project as well as i had build path but don't know, why it is not working .... :(