# LogCat: Could not find class 'com.jcraft.jsch.JSch'

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i'm trying to ssh connect from my android phone to a ssh server.

My import line:

```
    import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
```

and here the rest

```
    try{
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        //create SSH connection
        String host = "192.168.158.20";
        String user = "jan";
        String password = "mypassword";

        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("done");
      }
      catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
     }
```

I'm using Jsch (java ssh implementation) for that. I've downloaded the jsch-0.1.48.jar from the website and added it to my eclipse android project's build path via "right click project -> libraries -> Add Jars"

I can now see the jsch-0.1.48.jar file inside my Referenced Libraries so that seems to be ok.

When i start the debug i get a Could not find class 'com.jcraft.jsch.JSch' error from LogCat at the line 1.

Eclipse shows me no warnings or syntax errors.

Comment: Did you clean and build your project again?

Comment: The jsch jar file needs to be converted to DEX format and included in the APK. Otherwise you get a ClassNotFound error. See answer from Akki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert jsch jar file to DEX format and include the classes.dex along with the jar in the build path.

Comment: What do you mean by " include the classes.dex along with the jar in the build path" do we replace?

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder with name libs and import your jar file in there.

for more info [visit this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857539/noclassdeffounderror-when-googleanalyticstracker-getinstance/9857669#9857669)

Comment: i tried that and followed the link without success, although it seemed to have solved the problem for somebody with very similar problem