# Android NFC Sample -  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, android, nfc, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to run one of the sample applications that came with my eclipse download, particularly the NFC sample application. So I load it and run it but it keeps crashing with the following error.

Here is a link to the code itself 
http://source-android.frandroid.com/development/samples/NFCDemo/src/com/example/android/nfc/

```
08-04 23:49:40.056: D/dalvikvm(409): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
08-04 23:49:40.056: D/dalvikvm(409): VFY: dead code 0x0006-000b in Lcom/example/android/nfc/record/UriRecord;.<init> (Landroid/net/Uri;)V
08-04 23:49:40.066: I/dalvikvm(409): Could not find method com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument, referenced from method com.example.android.nfc.record.UriRecord.parseWellKnown
08-04 23:49:40.066: W/dalvikvm(409): VFY: unable to resolve static method 101: Lcom/google/common/base/Preconditions;.checkArgument (Z)V
08-04 23:49:40.066: D/dalvikvm(409): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000c
08-04 23:49:40.066: D/dalvikvm(409): VFY: dead code 0x000f-004f in Lcom/example/android/nfc/record/UriRecord;.parseWellKnown (Landroid/nfc/NdefRecord;)Lcom/example/android/nfc/record/UriRecord;
08-04 23:49:40.066: W/dalvikvm(409): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/android/nfc/record/UriRecord;
08-04 23:49:40.066: D/AndroidRuntime(409): Shutting down VM
08-04 23:49:40.076: W/dalvikvm(409): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.example.android.nfc.NdefMessageParser.getRecords(NdefMessageParser.java:47)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.example.android.nfc.NdefMessageParser.parse(NdefMessageParser.java:41)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.example.android.nfc.TagViewer.buildTagViews(TagViewer.java:105)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.example.android.nfc.TagViewer.resolveIntent(TagViewer.java:86)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.example.android.nfc.TagViewer.onCreate(TagViewer.java:59)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.example.android.nfc.record.UriRecord.<clinit>(UriRecord.java:51)
08-04 23:49:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  ... 18 more
```

I am new to Java and even newer to Android and not sure how to debug an Android application. I tried putting breakpoints in the code but that wasn't fired. so I would appreciate any help I can get from those on here.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of tries at this, it worked for me. Not sure what I eventually did to get it to but this worked, but I reloaded and then tried again and boom.

[NoClassDefFoundError when GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857539/noclassdeffounderror-when-googleanalyticstracker-getinstance/9857669#9857669)