# StringUtils class not working in Android

Tags: android, string-utils

I am using StringUtils class in Android code. but exception generated i.e. class not found. But already i used jar file for that class. Please help me!

Comment: Have you add jar file to build path ?

Comment: @Chirag Raval : yes i already used jar file for that.

Comment: This is working fine in simple java program. But when we use this same code in android that time generate this type of error. Please anybody have idea about that so please help me.

Comment: This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857539/noclassdeffounderror-when-googleanalyticstracker-getinstance/9857669#9857669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved with following code, We need not use StringUtils jar to add our project.

I create my own class i.e "RanjitString" replace with StringUtils.

```
public class RanjitString {
public static String substringBetween(String str, String open, String close) {
    if (str == null || open == null || close == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int start = str.indexOf(open);
    if (start != -1) {
        int end = str.indexOf(close, start + open.length());
        if (end != -1) {
            return str.substring(start + open.length(), end);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

And directly access the static method substringBetween:

```
String myxml="This is my xml with different tags";
String successResult = RanjitString.substringBetween(myxml,
                "<tag>", "</tag>");
```

This code is working for me...

Comment: See the other answer from @user2160667  , use TextUtils

Comment: @SerkanArıkuşu: But there is no substringBetween method in textUtils

Answer (score 25):

Try not to use external libraries. Look always for an Android alternative.

For this specific case, you could use: [`android.text.TextUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html)