# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to run tasks-android-sample

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been trying to run the sample code available at http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html

I have included all jar file needed to resolve the dependencies. My project doesn't contain any error but when i try to the program it give me following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential

I can see that the above class file is present in my reference libraries still the code is not running. Trying to solve this from 2 days. Please help

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857539/noclassdeffounderror-when-googleanalyticstracker-getinstance/9857669#9857669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should drop these jars in a folder named `/libs` at the root of your project. See this SO question: [How can I use external JARs in an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

Comment: got it working....thanks....found out that jar should be /libs folder. Beside, some of the jar need to be added to build path. Some got added automatically from the classpath of other. Adding them manually gave errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included your libs in the java build path and checked it in the Order and Export Tab?
i.e

Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export > and finally, checkmark your imported library.